# Unable to join domain from Site-to-Site VPN Server

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2019, site-to-site-vpn

I work for a small business that is looking to expand to the cloud so that our remote workers can access more of our systems. As a software dev and keen IT enthusiast, I jumped at the opportunity to get my hands dirty with this project. After spending the last 2 weeks attempting to get a test solution working on my PC with HyperV, I have a new found admiration for networking majors.

**My Solution**
Since we still have most people working in the office on a daily basis, I thought that we should make use of a Site-to-Site VPN connection and treat our office as a branch and the cloud like head office. Simple, right?

To test all this out, I set up my environment in HyperV, with all firewalls turned off, just to make communication a bit easier. Please be aware that my selection of subnet came from a tutorial.

All servers are running Windows Server 2019 Standard

**Cloud Servers** - *10.1.1.0/24*

1. ***SRV01***   (Domain Controller)

   - 10.1.1.4
2. ***VPN01***  (Remote Access)

   - 10.1.1.10
   - 192.168.15.20 *External IP*

**Office** - *10.1.2.0/24*

3. **VPN02** (Remote Access)

   - 10.1.2.150
   - 192.168.15.21 *External IP*

**The Issue**
Besides my limited knowledge, the issue that I am having is connecting **VPN02** to the domain. I have the Site-to-Site VPN working, and I can ping **SRV01** from **VPN02**, but I am unable to ping the other way. **VPN01** can ping both servers, and vice versa. Running `nslookup` from **VPN02** has seemingly good results as I can get the IP as well as the server name of both "cloud" servers.

I have setup 2 sites in *AD Sites and Services*, added the correct subnets to each site and linked them. I'm not really sure where to go from here. I know that I don't have the experience, but I also don't have the budget to get a professional in so I am all that I have. Plus, I like to add more things to my IT toolbelt.

Thanks in advanced.

**EDIT:** Adjusted IP ranges to not be on the same subnet. Still same issues though.

Comment: IMHO you setup the network wrongly, you should NOT using the same Subnets for using different locations, you will need to have different for been able to route them

Comment: @djdomi What I am hearing is that I don't know how to read a subnet calculator. haha. I will adjust and come back with my results.